# why can't i change the language of my dataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have tried multiple ways and i'm sure the jQuery is setting the table right but isn't changing the language. This are some things i've tried and i don't know why isn't changing:

```
$('#data-table').dataTable( {
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }
        } );


$("#data-table").dataTable({
            "language": {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }
        });

            $('#data-table').dataTable( {
            "language": {
               "sUrl": "media/language/custom_lang_spanish.txt"
            }
        } );
```

Comment: What version of dataTables are you using? Your code works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zwv440u8/**

Answer (score 0):

what's going on dude? hehe

Here's the solution, you have to put the path to your json lang file, for example:

in your javascript:
"url": "assets/plugins/DataTables/json/Spanish.json"

or if you are working with CodeIgniter:
"url": ""

And then, download the Spanish.json to your folder.

Hope this help